# Model 'donation.donation' does not exist in registry?

Tags: odoo

i tried to uninstall donation odoo

but it interrupted so when try to run my odoo an erreur was printing always ,
 pleaseee i need a help
thx i use odoo v10

> File "/home/ikram/odoo/odoo-10/odoo/models.py", line 531, in
>   _build_model
>       raise TypeError("Model %r does not exist in registry." % name) TypeError: Model 'donation.donation' does not exist in registry.
>   2018-06-01 23:00:35,095 9787 ERROR client-z.odoo.local
>   odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_cron: Unexpected exception while processing
>   cron job {'function': u'get_next_mail', 'create_uid': 1, 'args': None,
>   'create_date': '2018-05-28 10:14:01.583127', 'name': u'Run Event
>   Reminder', 'interval_number': 30, 'interval_type': u'minutes',
>   'numbercall': -1, 'nextcall': '2018-06-01 22:44:02', 'priority': 5,
>   'doall': False, 'write_date': '2018-05-28 10:14:01.583127', 'active':
>   True, 'user_id': 1, 'model': u'calendar.alarm_manager', 'write_uid':
>   1, 'id': 8} Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/ikram/odoo/odoo-10/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_cron.py", line 249,
>   in _process_jobs
>       registry = odoo.registry(db_name)   File "/home/ikram/odoo/odoo-10/odoo/**init**.py", line 52, in registry
>       return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)   File "/home/ikram/odoo/odoo-10/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 59, in
>   **new**
>       return cls.new(db_name)   File "/home/ikram/odoo/odoo-10/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 83, in new
>       odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)   File
>   "/home/ikram/odoo/odoo-10/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 335, in
>   load_modules
>       force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)   File "/home/ikram/odoo/odoo-10/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 237, in
>   load_marked_modules
>       loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules,
>   perform_checks=perform_checks)   File
>   "/home/ikram/odoo/odoo-10/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 131, in
>   load_module_graph
>       model_names = registry.load(cr, package)   File "/home/ikram/odoo/odoo-10/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 263, in load
>       model = cls._build_model(self, cr)   File "/home/ikram/odoo/odoo-10/odoo/models.py", line 531, in _build_model
>       raise TypeError("Model %r does not exist in registry." % name) TypeError: Model 'donation.donation' does not exist in registry.

Comment: Did you have a the  model `donation.donation` ?

Answer (score 0):

Run Odoo with attribute
-i donation
or 
-u donation

Module should be reinstalled. Then just simply uninstall it.

Comment: /usr/bin/python2.7: can't open file '/home/ikram/odoo/odoo-10/odoo-bin  -u donation': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: First select the database and then the module, like this  -d database -u donation

Comment: Are you sure your path is correct? It looks like it isnt.